# System.Runtime.Caching works locally but does not work when deployed to a web server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, memorycache

I have the following class CacheHelper that I use throughout my application that has multiple libraries. The Caching works fine when I test it on my local, but when it is deployed to a webserver, it seems to not work (GET returns null). Any ideas?

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object GetValue(string key)
    {
        var memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        return memoryCache.Get(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="absExpiration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Add(string key, object value, DateTimeOffset absExpiration)
    {
        var memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        return memoryCache.Add(key, value, absExpiration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    public void Delete(string key)
    {
        var memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        if (memoryCache.Contains(key)) memoryCache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Usage throughout my application projects:

```
var cacheHelper = new CacheHelper();
var cachedValue = cacheHelper.GetValue(keyName);
```

Here is how I set it:

```
cacheHelper.Add(keyName, cacheValue, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30));
```

Comment: Is your site hosted in a web farm? Is something recycling the app pool often?

Comment: Is something unexpectedly calling `Delete`?

Comment: no, deletes are in one place and they don't get called unless actively executed. site app pool recycles every 1740 minutes.

Comment: Make use of: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.removedcallback.aspx and possibly doing some logging to determine when items are being added to cache and then removed. Might help with troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: *"they don't get called unless actively executed"* - could something be calling this unexpectedly? *"site app pool recycles every 1740 minutes"* - you know other things can cause it to recycle? (like if I edit your web.config file, just to give one example). I think you need to add some logging to help diagnose. P.S. I only spotted your response by chance, you need to @ tag someone to get their attention when replying specifically to them.

Comment: @Richardissimo sure! thanks for the tip. Yeh, my next thing would be to add logging I guess and see what's what.

Comment: @mjwills My multiple worker processes is set to 1. so, hopefully that answers your question.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using it in the controller, you are most likely using a new instance on very request.

Comment: That would mean it shouldn't work on my local either. But it does.